# How can I remove all CSS classes of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript

Is there a simple way to remove all the CSS classes of the child elements of a particular HTML element using JavaScript? I only know how to remove each one individually.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "remove all the classes of child elements"? Can you offer an example of input and output data?

Comment: Read this [mcve]

Comment: Further to the previous comment, please also read the "*[ask]*" guidance. This should help you to ask better questions, get better answers and leave more useful information for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) to remove the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute from child elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#example *').forEach(element => {
  element.removeAttribute('class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all classes from an Element, set its `className` to an empty String.

```
function removeAllClasses(elem){
 elem.className = "";
}
```

To get all children of an Element, you can use a query selector:

```
function getAllChildren(id){
 return document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} *`);//or document.querySelectorAll("#"+id+" *")
}
```

You can use a `for` loop or `forEach` to remove the classes from all the children of an element.

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll("#id *");
for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
 children[i].className = "";
}
//or
children.forEach(function(i){
 i.className = "";
});
```

Demo:

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
.large{
  font-size: 5em;
 }
```

```html
<div id="test">
<div class="red large">text</div>
<span class="red large">text</span>
<select class="red large">text</select>
<div class="red large">First layer
<div class="red large">second layer
<span class="red large">Nested third layer</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
function removeAllClasses(elem){
   elem.className = "";
}
function getAllChildren(id){
     return document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} *`);
}
var children = getAllChildren('test');
for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
  removeAllClasses(children[i]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I guess the op wants like `elements.forEach(removeAllClasses);` or something like that

Comment: Yeah, this sets the class name for elem only, not the child elements of it